# Match text via Regex that is within an HTML tag

Tags: regex

Via a Regex, I'm trying to match the word `one`, only when it's within an HTML `<p>` tag.

1. `<p>zero one two three</p>`
2. `zero one two<p>three</p>`
3. `<p>zero one <b>two</b></p><p>three</p>`
4. `<p>two</p>three one`

#1 and #3 above should be matches.  It feels like I need a lookahead that makes sure there is a closing `</p>` tag without an opening `<p>` tag that comes before it (or a lookbehind that does the opposite).  But I can't seem to come up with the right expression. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: What about <p>.*?(one).*?<\/p>

Comment: That does work @VincentBeltman, thanks.  For where I need to use this, the answer by AvinashRaj works better because it captures just the word "one" and not the whole paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match the string `one` which is inside the `<p>` tag.

```
\bone\b(?=(?:(?!<\/?p>).)*<\/p>)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xE6aD0/2)

Comment: This can also match <p>two</p>three `one` </p>

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj I think this is what I'm after... I would have never have come up with this! Let me double check in the morning.

Comment: @vks you're right about that matching, but for my purposes (in this case), I'm able to assume valid markup.

Answer (score 2):

```
<p>(?:(?!<\/p>).)*(\bone\b)(?:(?!<\/p>).)*<\/p>
```

You can try this.Just grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/xT7yD8/12

Comment: Thanks @vks this is good.  I'm using C# btw.  The one from AvinashRaj might be a bit better because it's capturing "one" without capturing the P tags or anything else, but I'll double check in the morning.